# Access Documents directory contents in files app in ios 15

Tags: ios, swift, file-sharing, ios15, documentsdirectory

In my app, I want to expose the documents directory of the app in files app. I have set UIFileSharingEnabled and LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace to YES in info.plist.
This works perfectly while using iOS 14 simulator. But the same does not work on iOS 15 simulator.
What is the fix for this issue?